# What is the penalty for the dummy failing to follow suit?

Tags: bridge

I failed to have the dummy follow suit because the remaining card of that suit was accidentally hidden under a card of another suit. This was discovered later in the game, and treated as a [normal revoke](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/what-is-the-penalty-for-failing-to-follow-suit). Should the penalty have been reduced because the dummy is face up and *everyone* (opponents included) failed to notice that it had only 12 visible cards to begin with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the penalty for failing to follow suit?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/what-is-the-penalty-for-failing-to-follow-suit)

Comment: "Standard American" is a bidding system, not a game variant. Were you playing duplicate bridge or rubber bridge, or a strange other? And you were penalised "as if" you reneged because *you did in fact* renege.

Comment: Feel free to object to my rewrite, but I wanted to make it clearer what the crux of this question is because I think it's an interesting variant of the linked question and not quite a duplicate (though the answer is probably the same).

Comment: Close voters please note: the penalty for dummy revoking is not the same as for another player; and BCG should not be telling inquirers that it is.

Comment: Yes, this is a unique question, and does not deserve to be closed.

Answer (score 4):

The actual answer is in Law 64D

> there is no trick penalty for the established revoke ...3. if the revoke was made in failing to play any card 
>   faced  on,  or  belonging  to  a  hand  faced  on,  the
>   table, including a card from dummy’s hand.

But a clearer view is given in [In bridge, is there a penalty if dummy incorrectly lays down his hand?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/32813/1644) (not quite a duplicate but very close).